# Missing packages

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm getting the following errors. The software repositories are setup properly so I'm not sure what's going on as it is 12.04 LTS shouldn't these be valid?

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-common=129
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
postgresql-client-common

The following NEW packages will be installed:
postgresql-client-common postgresql-common

0 to upgrade, 2 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.

Need to get 25.1 kB/121 kB of archives.

After this operation, 596 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 

WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
postgresql-common
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y

Err http://lips.csiro.au/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main postgresql-client-common all 129ubuntu1 404  Not Found

Failed to fetch http://lips.csiro.au/ubuntu/pool/main/p/postgresql-common/postgresql-client-common_129ubuntu1_all.deb 404  Not Found
```

Answer (score 1):

As your error message says

```
Failed to fetch http://lips.csiro.au/ubuntu/pool/main/p/postgresql-common/postgresql-client-common_129ubuntu1_all.deb 404  Not Found
```

The host isn't reachable, not ping-able and not trace-able.

Therefore use another PPA, e.g.

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main
```

Comment: Well this is crazy, its all working now! Yesterday that domain resolved fine and I could see the contents of the directory but it did not have the exact above package file so my question was why is apt-get looking for a version that (I thought) was no longer available? Anyway all good now, thanks

Comment: @FarhanRizwi  Since you're a new user, if this answer helped you, don't forget to mark it as solved by clicking on the grey check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is all working now, not sure why that particular package was missing yesterday but is there now. I understand things can go out-of-date and sometimes you have to add different repositories but I was just confused that an LTS was having trouble with default versions. Anyway all working now